# Fill column by comparing col from one data frame and row from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data Frame1:

[image: Data Frame 1]

Data Frame 2 with time col as Output:

[image: Data Frame 2 with time Col as output]

The output is shown in Yellow Color (`time`)

```
new = pd.melt(, id_vars =['a','b','c','d'], 
    value_vars='1a','1b','1c','1d','1e'],
    var_name ='node', value_name ='time')
new1 = pd.merge(file, new, on=['a','b','c','d','node'],how='left')
print(new1)
new1.to_excel("new1.xlsx",index=False)
```

Question: How to get `col time` from data frame 1 and data frame 2

Output Shown in Yellow Color in `time`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Your solution not working? Try change `new1 = pd.merge(file, new, on=['a','b','c','d','e','node'],how='left')` to `new1 = pd.merge(file, new, on=['a','b','c','d','node'],how='left')`

Comment: You've not given `input2` dataset.

Comment: Columns `a ,b, c, d` are text columns and can not be compared to columns `1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, 1e` which are numeric. You question is not clear.

Comment: @jezrael,  That 'e' was typo mistake, but still not working. Tried melt function but didn't work.

Comment: try `new = df.melt(id_vars =['a','b','c','d'], 
    value_vars='1a','1b','1c','1d','1e'],
    var_name ='node', value_name ='time')`

Comment: @AzharKhan, consider Image2 as Input2. To have more understanding i use to Input2.

Comment: @jezrael, this is melt function which i tried but not working.

Comment: What means not working?

Comment: @jezrael, melt function transform row into col and its respective value. But in our case ,  output contain duplicates values, 

There are 10 rows here but output is more than the expected result. 

I am not sure merge on left is correctly working or not. 

Suggest any loop function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.